# UEFI boot manager in ext4 folder

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, efi

How can I boot Linux (ext4) with UEFI boot manager in the same partition (without separated UEFI partition)?

**Example**: I have only one partition on my Windows ssd (NTFS) and an EFI folder in the root. Motherbord's UEFI can find this folder and boot the system.

Comment: What is the size of your ESP (EFI System Partition)?   Typically Windows creates a small ESP and you may need to be able to increase the size of the ESP if you want the ESP to support booting multiple OSes.  You then need to create a new subdirectory whose name depends on the OS (See https://uefi.org/registry) and add the appropriate OS boot files to that subdirectory.  Finally, you need to fix up or add the appropriate UEFI BOOTXXXX variables.

Comment: What does your Linux boot command (on grubx64.efi grub.cfg?) look like? Maybe (if your ext4 partition is smaller than about 2TB) you can add a FAT32, recommended 100-550MB, EFI partition behind the ext4 partition?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the UEFI partition is in a FAT system file. It has to be handled by the firmware then don’t expect fancy conventions.

But the boot loader inside the UEFI can handle any filesystem. The Windows boot loader will handle NTFS, the Grub2 boot loader many Linux file systems, and we can imagine other system with their own boot loader (FreeBSD…)

Comment: I mean boot UEFI bootloader (on the ext4 partition) from motherboard firmware directly. I updated my question.

Comment: Oops, this is a really different question ! The UEFI partition is made to be launch an OS, not to host it. Its filesystem, FAT, should be considered obsoletes for serious purpuse (no jounalisation, no permission handling).

Comment: My system partition is not FAT32, its NTFS :) Just UEFI bootloader not in separate partition but right in the system one.

Comment: You have a fancy system... What does the disk manager tell you about your disk and their partitions ? On my recent system, the first partition is "Healty (EFI partition system)" and it is not the `C:\`. How did you find th "bootloader" ?

Comment: Yes, usually windows installer create 100mb efi partition. But in my case I have only one partition (disk manager as well as diskpart confirm this). I read somewhere that the UEFI firmware smart enough to find the bootloader in the NTFS partition. Now I am looking for a way to do this with Debian. Bootloader located in the EFI folder in the root.

Comment: Sometimes the Windows installer reports an error because the EFI is formatted NTFS (https://www.diskpart.com/articles/images/windows-detected-that-the-efi-system-partition-was-formated-as-ntfs-5740/efi-system-partition-error.jpg). But if you have a fancy firmware which supports NFTS, this doesn’t mean you can make it support ext4.

Comment: I don't think it's fancy. It is regular Gigabyte motherboard with stock firmware. But I can't find any info about supported FS.

Comment: If I read the UEFI specification (a free 2540 pages PDF file), you read : « The file system supported by the Extensible Firmware Interface is based on the FAT file system. EFI defines a specific version of FAT that is explicitly documented and testable. Conformance to the EFI specification and its associate reference documents is the only definition of FAT that needs to be implemented to support EFI. To differentiate the EFI file system from pure FAT, a new partition file system type has been defined. »… then a UEFI partition is FAT… anything else is not UEFI but could be inspired by.